# How to use hyperdb to separate and share a user dataset between wordpress installs?

Tags: users, user-meta, hyperdb

I'm looking for a way to separate my users and usermeta table to be in a different database than my main WP install. The end goal is sharing these table over a number of WP installs.

From what I read, HyperDB should allow for this, however their documentation is a little sparse when it comes to creating and linking datasets --- which is where I believe I should be looking.

I've tried something along the lines of this without success:

```
$wpdb->add_database(array(
    'host'     => DB_HOST,
    'user'     => DB_USER,
    'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
    'name'     => 'my_user_db_name',
    'write'    => 0,
    'read'     => 1,
    'dataset'  => 'user',
    'timeout'  => 0.2,
));

$wpdb->add_table( $user, $wpdb->base_prefix . 'users' );
$wpdb->add_table( $user, $wpdb->base_prefix . 'usermeta' );
```

But this wasn't successful. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
~Cam

Answer (score 4):

I believe [Crazycoolcam](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/28144/crazycoolcam) spelled the table incorrectly, `user_meta` vs `usermeta`. You may also want to define the else case, what happens if the table is not user.

Try this:

```
<?php 
        $wpdb->add_database(array( //Connect to Users Database
        'host'     => DB_HOST, // I am using the same host for my two DBs
        'user'     => DB_USER, // I am using the same username for my two DBs
        'password' => DB_PASSWORD, // I am using the same p/w for my two DBs
        'name'     => 'my_user_db_name', 
        'write'    => 0, // Change to 1 if you want your slave site's the power to update user data.
        'read'     => 1,
        'dataset'  => 'user'
    ));

    $wpdb->add_database(array( // Main Database
        'host'     => DB_HOST,
        'user'     => DB_USER,
        'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
        'name'     => DB_NAME,
        'write'    => 1, // Change to 1 if you want your slave site's the power to update user data.
        'read'     => 1,
        'dataset' => 'global'
    ));

    $wpdb->add_callback('user_callback');

    function user_callback($query, $wpdb) {
        if ( $wpdb->base_prefix . 'users' == $wpdb->table || $wpdb->base_prefix . 'usermeta' == $wpdb->table) {
            return 'user'; 
        } else {
            return 'global';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this update. I probably did spell the usermeta table incorrectly.
At this point in my journey, I figured out how to make multi-site work for me, and that has greatly simplified my user sharing.
I hope that your response helps others though!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Here is what I did:

```
$wpdb->add_database(array( //Connect to Users Database
    'host'     => DB_HOST, // I am using the same host for my two DBs
    'user'     => DB_USER, // I am using the same username for my two DBs
    'password' => DB_PASSWORD, // I am using the same p/w for my two DBs
    'name'     => 'my_user_db_name', 
    'write'    => 0, // Change to 1 if you want your slave site's the power to update user data.
    'read'     => 1,
    'dataset'  => 'user',
    'timeout'  => 0.2,
));

$wpdb->add_database(array( // Main Database
    'host'     => DB_HOST,
    'user'     => DB_USER,
    'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
    'name'     => DB_NAME,
));

$wpdb->add_callback('user_callback');
function user_callback($query, $wpdb) {
    if ( $wpdb->base_prefix . 'users' == $wpdb->table || $wpdb->base_prefix . 'user_meta' == $wpdb->table) {
        return 'user'; 
    }
}
```

Be warned that if plugins have tweaked with your admin permissions *(I have one that does)*, the sites you connect will have to have been tweaked as well.

I have seen several people with this question: How to share users between Wordpress installations while not using the same DB? With HyperDB, I was able to solve this!

Comment: On further testing, this doesn't seem to work, however, I haven't figured out why or what is missing.

Comment: doesn't really work, neither does the admin rights, the problem lies here :
No databases available with wp_users (wpusers)
No databases available with wp_user_meta (wpuser_meta)

Comment: @ManuelK You are probably right. Not long after I asked this question almost a decade ago, I abandoned this approach in favor of building this network of sites with WP multisite and it has worked much better.  Thanks for chiming in.