# How to use HyperDB plugin in a existing wpmu

Tags: multisite, hyperdb

I am using wordpress multisite v3.5.1 in a single db called `maindb`. And i have also 5 blog. They are **bazar**(main blog), **demo1**, **demo2**, **demo3** and **demo4**. In future i want add more blog but i want to create a database for each blog and want to use them(but also in a single network).

as like
**maindb** for **bazar**(main blog) blog,
**db1** for **demo1** blog,
**db2** for **demo2** blog,
**db3** for **demo3** blog,
**db4** for **demo4** blog ...

How i do that with **hyperdb**? how would `db-config.php` code will be look like for my this condition? please help me.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88720/how-to-use-hyperdb-to-separate-and-share-a-user-dataset-between-wordpress-instal

Comment: If this the old, *separate*, [WordPress MU](http://mu.wordpress.org), or the [WordPress multisite network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) feature that is built into WordPress now?

Comment: @bungeshea.. i am sorry i can't understand your words