# WordPress Multisites or Multiple WP Single sites?

Tags: multisite, database, subdomains, hyperdb, shared-user-tables

So I am pondering over a decision to use WordPress Multi-Sites or just use Multiple WP Single sites. The reason is that the company site is broken down into multiple departments.

```
Maindotcom (WP SITE)
 /about
 /department1 (WP SUBSITE)
 /department2 (WP SUBSITE)
 department3.maindotcom (WP SUBSITE)
 /contact
 /blog
```

I would like...

- to Have a Super admin that has access across all wp sites.
- to use both, subdomains and subfolders, in the chosen setup (see example above).
- to know which is better for SEO?
- for all sites to share media folder
- for all sites to share the main template file
- have maximum compatibility with plugins
- each site to have its own database.

I have looked into using WP HyperDB which has the ability to add on remote servers and Master/slave setups.

And I have seen solutions to share same user across multiple installs using HyperDB: [How to use hyperdb to separate and share a user dataset between wordpress installs?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88720/how-to-use-hyperdb-to-separate-and-share-a-user-dataset-between-wordpress-instal)

Please let me know any solution

Answer (score 1):

Rather than post this as a bunch of comments, I'm going to make this an answer.

Your requirements/questions:

> to Have a Super admin that has access across all wp sites.

That's a hallmark of Multisite.

> to use both, subdomains and subfolders, in the chosen setup (see example above).

You can accomplish this with something like the [Multi Network plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/), as I understand it.

> to know which is better for SEO?

Someone else would have to answer that; I'm not an SEO expert.

> for all sites to share media folder

This isn't something that WordPress Multisite does, so you'd need to find a plugin (or build one / hire someone to build one) to do this. You'd be in the same boat if you use a group of single-site installations, too.

> for all sites to share the main template file

You can use the same theme on all the sites in a Multisite network; you can even set a default theme for new sites in the network using the [`WP_DEFAULT_THEME` constant](https://wpseek.com/constant/wp_default_theme/) in `wp-config.php`.

> each site to have its own database

Multisite separates sites into their own tables in the database, with a common table for the users (all users are able to be added to any of the sites). eg, if you're using the default `wp_` prefix in your database, then for these sites:

```
Maindotcom (WP SITE)
 /about
 /department1 (WP SUBSITE)
 /department2 (WP SUBSITE)
 department3.maindotcom (WP SUBSITE)
 /contact
 /blog
```

... your database would be something like this:

```
// tables for maindotcom
wp_posts
wp_postmeta
wp_options
...

// tables for maindotcom/department1
wp_2_posts
wp_2_postmeta
wp_2_options
...
```

...and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful written-out comment! That last part concerning the table,  I knew that Multisites make diff tables inside the database for each new site added. I was looking for a way to make a new site added, to have its own database and table. Some say that HyperDb can do it

Comment: I've heard of HyperDB, but I've got no experience with it at all. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that heads-up on the Multi Network plugin

Comment: After pondering more. I realize that not all plugins work with Multi-sites. And what is more, if one site breaks, the whole site breaks... So I went with Multiple Installations.