# Installed in root, want second in subdirectory

Tags: multisite, directory, installation

### Current situation

I am trying to plan ahead and avoid any grievous pitfalls and/or headaches in adding a second domain/site for a client.

1. WP is currently installed in root
2. The client wants a second site created for a new brand that ***may*** end up as it's own entity, so **separate** public facing **domains**.
3. The root site already has almost 200 pages + posts
4. I'd like to keep a [central user base](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60521/multiple-single-installs-of-wordpress-with-a-central-user-base) if possible.
5. They have quite a few plugins running
6. I use [IWP](http://infinitewp.com/), so keeping track of updates and backups really isn't that difficult.

### Question(s)

1. Is it possible to create a subdir install with a separate domain pointing at it (with out moving the first install to it's own subdir)?
2. Would it be more beneficial to convert to a multisite install instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, I did it here for example:

http://krimsonkloverdev.malbert.me/ - dev site with seperate wordpress install
http://www.malbert.me/ - main site on root level.

I set everything up at my host, I'd recommend you just contact them first and be sure you can have separate database installs as that's basically all you need.

Comment: An explanation **how** it can be done would be much better.

Comment: There's tons of hosts...  Have no idea the options everyone needs / has